# What does <<< mean?

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, command

What does <<< mean? Here is an example:

```
$ sed 's/a/b/g' <<< "aaa"
bbb
```

Is it something general that works with more Linux commands?

It looks like it's feeding the `sed` program with the string `aaa`, but isn't << or < usually used for that?

Comment: it seems `<` is for passing file (or directory), `<< @` for passing multiple lines (similar to the `banner` command in [tag:cisco] switches; as terminated by a custom string `@` in this case), and `<<<` to pass a string (instead of file). test them yourself with `cat` and you'll grasp it very quickly.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Others have answered the basic question: What is it? (Answer: It's a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings).)

Let's look at why it's useful.

You can also feed a string to a command's stdin like this:

```
echo "$string" | command
```

However in Bash, introducing a pipe means the individual commands are run in subshells. Consider this:

```
echo "hello world" | read first second
echo $second $first
```

The output of the 2nd echo command prints just a single space. Whaaaa? What happened to my variables? Because the read command is in a pipeline, it is run in a subshell. It correctly reads 2 words from its stdin and assigns to the variables. But then the command completes, *the subshell exits* and the variables are lost.

Sometimes you can work around this with braces:

```
echo "hello world" | {
    read first second
    echo $second $first
}
```

That's OK if your need for the values is contained, but you still don't have those variables in the current shell of your script.

To remedy this confusing situation, use a here string:

```
read first second <<< "hello world"
echo $second $first
```

Ah, much better!

Comment: In addition to here-strings, [process substutitions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) are very useful for the same reasons.

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation of <<< as well as pipes and sub-shells! I learned both from this.

Comment: One note, with the simple `echo ...|read` example, the pipeline can work to set the variables in the current shell if you (1) enable the "lastpipe" shell option (`shopt -s lastpipe`) and (2) disable job control (`set +m`)

Comment: @glennjackman, What's the different between here-strings vs replacing it with an echoed temporary file?

Comment: Functionally nothing. With a here string, you don't have to delete a temp file.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows' Ubuntu Bash: `dradcliffe:~$ read first second <<< big joe // nothing`

Comment: First the here string is a single string so if it contains whitespace you need quotes. Second the read command doesn't output anything so you'll have to clarify "nothing"

Comment: Very interesting. The case you give does not result in unexpected behavior using zsh.

Comment: On my zsh, the output for `echo $second $first` is `world hello`

Comment: For zsh the last command of a pipeline is run in the parent shell ([blog post](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=178)), though unfortunately I couldn't(?) infer this directly from the [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines). Anyway, when to use a subshell is apparently [not specified by posix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean).

Comment: Am I right to think, this is a "bashism"? It's not backed by POSIX, is it?

Comment: bash usually steals features from Korn shell or zsh. I don't know who invented it.

Answer (score 152):

`<<<` denotes a here string.

```
$ cat <<< 'hi there'
hi there
```

It passes the word on the right to the standard input of the command on the left.

---

`<<` denotes a here document.

```
$ cat <<EOF
> hi
> there
> EOF
hi
there
```

`EOF` can be any word.

Here documents are commonly used in shell scripts to create whole files or to display long messages.

```
cat > some-file <<FILE
foo
bar
bar bar
foo foo
FILE
```

---

`<` passes the contents of a file to a command's standard input.

```
$ cat < /etc/fstab
/dev/sda2               /boot   ext4            nosuid,noexec,nodev,rw,noatime,nodiratime       0 2
/dev/sda4               /       ext4            rw,noatime,nodiratime,  0 1
/dev/sdb5               /var    ext4            nosuid,noexec,nodev,rw,relatime 0 2
 ...
```

Comment: Is there a reason why someone would want `cat < /etc/fstab` instead of just `cat /etc/fstab`? Or is `cat` just a suboptimal example here?

Comment: In the first case, cat opens the file, and in the second case, the shell opens the file, passing it as cat's standard input.  quote from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258931/difference-between-cat-and-cat

Comment: I can't think of a reason why `cat < file` would ever be better than `cat file`.  However, there are some cases where there is a difference -- for example, `grep string file` is different from `grep string < file` in that the second form doesn't prefix "file:" in front of every line.  "cat file | grep string" is better written as "grep string < file".  Not that any of this is worth doing for performance alone these days, but it is better coding practice.

Comment: @star In `cat < /etc/fstab`, the shell opens the file, passing it as `cat`'s standard input, whereas in `cat /etc/fstab`, `cat` opens the file. I think you'd interchanged them.

Comment: @BrianC `cat < file > foo` would not create or overwrite `foo` if `file` could not be opened and so wouldn't potentially zap a file in an error scenario while `cat file > foo` would create/overwrite `foo` in that case.

Comment: Hi @ed-morton - In testing, `cat < foo > file` doesn't actually overwrite foo; and If there is an rare error reading the input file, `cat foo` is able to report the file name, whereas it cannot when presented with a stream via `< file`.  Of course, BOTH forms are absolutely terrible shell programming practice and should never be done.  Instead, use the `cp` command, or output to an intermediate file and use `if [ -s foo.tmp ]` to test for output file validity before then moving the output over the top of any existing file called foo.

Comment: @BrianC I didn't suggest that `cat < foo > file` would overwrite `foo`, of course it doesn't. You misread my comment, it has nothing to do with overwriting the input file. I was providing a case where `cat < file` would be better than `cat file` in response to your comment ["I can't think of a reason why cat < file would ever be better than cat file"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean/80368?noredirect=1#comment978966_80368)

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at the [Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). This notation is part of what's called a *here documents* & *here strings*. It allows you the ability to generate multi-line data input as one continuous string. The variation you're asking about is called a *here string*.

*excerpt from Bash man page*

```
Here Strings
   A variant of here documents, the format is:

          <<<word

   The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.
```

**NOTE:** For more info you can also check out the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) which discusses Here Strings.

Answer (score 9):

It means here strings.

```
<<< strings
```

The strings is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

In your example, strings `aaa` is feed to sed command via stdin.