# How to wrap a string around large gzip file?

Tags: ubuntu, cat

I have a large (several GB) `xml` file that is missing a root element. I might use `cat` on ubuntu to wrap around a `<root>` element around the content.

How can I achieve this without having to extract and repack the content?

It works if I create separate prefix and postfix gz files, and concatenate them with cat. But could I do better, without having to create explicit pre-/postfix gz files? Can I achieve the same on the fly?

```
echo "<root>" | gzip > prefix.gz
echo "</root>" | gzip > postfix.gz
cat prefix.gz input.xml.gz postfix.gz > newfile.gz
```

Comment: since you're dealing with a multi-GB file, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690823) might be interesting to take a look at regarding the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use here strings and a succession of commands:

```
(gzip <<<"<root>"; cat input.xml.gz; gzip <<<"</root>") > newfile.gz
```

Here strings are described in [What does <<< mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80362/86440) and in [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings).

Comment: `gzip` may refuse to compress short strings like that without `-f`. EDIT: No it doesn't, since it's from stdin.

Comment: While I don't understand exactly, especially the `<<<`, it works as expected!

Comment: See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80362/86440) or [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) for a description of `<<<`.